# Почему clientWidth выдает неверное значение?

Tags: javascript, html

Файл подключен в шапке:

```js
(function() {
    var current_width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    console.log(current_width); 
})();
```

Всегда выводит в консоль 980, независимо от размера окна. Если ввести в консоль `documentElement.clientWidth` уже после загрузки окна, то все нормально. Как с этим бороться? Мне нужно знать ширину окна в самом начале загрузки страницы.

Comment: Так вставьте скрипт первым ребёнком после тега <body>

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко а можно ли узнать ширину окна раньше, чем body? Я хочу сделать редирект при определенной ширине экрана и нет смысла грузить head, если мое условие выполняется.

Comment: а вообще, я вынес ваш скрипт в отедльный файл и вставил его сразу после title. И размер показывается правильно...

Comment: А если `window.innerWidth` ?

Comment: Ещё только редиректов на ширину окна не хватало...

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/metrics-window